# Checking if enum type contains constant with given name

Tags: java, generics, enums

I have multiple enums in my code:

```
public enum First { a, b, c, d; }

public enum Second { e, f, g; }
```

I want to have one method that checks to see if a value is present in any enum using valueOf() without writing one for each enum type.  For example (this code does not run):

```
public boolean enumTypeContains(Enum e, String s) {
    try {
        e.valueOf(s);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Usage:

```
enumTypeContains(First,"a"); // returns true
enumTypeContains(Second,"b"); // returns false
```

Any ideas on how to do something like this?

Comment: I added all three answers (e.g. the code in them) to my [github repository stackoverflow-examples](https://github.com/ePaul/stackoverflow-examples/blob/master/src/de/fencing_game/paul/examples/EnumUtils.java).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is your solution:

```
public static boolean contains(Class<? extends Enum> clazz, String val) {
   Object[] arr = clazz.getEnumConstants();
   for (Object e : arr) {
      if (((Enum) e).name().equals(val)) {
         return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

It gets all of the enum's vaules and checks to see if it has a value that shares a name with the parameter you passed in.  If so, then it returns true, otherwise it returns false.

This has been tested and works.  Test code:

```
public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(contains(Haha.class, "Bad"));
      System.out.println(contains(Haha.class, "Happy"));
      System.out.println(contains(Haha.class, "Sad"));
   }

   static enum Haha {
      Happy, Sad;
   }
}
```

Prints:

```
false
true
true
```

Comment: You could restrict it to `enum` types at compile time by making the type of the first parameter `Class<? extends Enum<?>>`. Then you wouldn't need to do any runtime checks.

Comment: @Colin, thanks for the tip.  Not sure why I didn't think of that earlier.

Comment: I'd like to point out that in general using exceptions to manipulate the flow of your program (except in exceptional cases) is a bad idea.

Comment: @BugsPray: Now please measure which of these is faster for your usual use case (e.g. the enum types which you are actually using in your program, and the names you are actually using to check this). The exception throwing variant has some overhead depending on the stack depth (assuming the `valueOf` method has a fast implementation), this variant needs to copy the value array and loop through it.

Comment: My use case doesn't rely on efficiency or speed, as the function will only run about 10 times or so.  It does appear that this solution works much faster than the other.  Ran it through a simple test (ran the function 3000000 times) and the runtime for the other solution was about 20x less.  It appears to be increasing geometrically.

Comment: @BugsPray: geometrically on which variable?

Comment: Neither parameter is variable in my tests.  I don't know if there is any caching going on or anything.  Your (the third) answer is also running on the same order of complexity as this one with this test.

Comment: Glad to help!  Iterating through all enums of a type is usually really fast because there are never a huge amount of enums in a type.

Answer (score 10):

This should work:

```
public <E extends Enum<E>> boolean enumTypeContains(Class<E> e, String s) {
    try {
        Enum.valueOf(e, s);
        return true;
    }
    catch(IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You then have to call it by

```
enumTypeContains(First.class, "a");
```

I'm not sure if simply searching through the values (like in the answer from jinguy) might be faster than creating and throwing an exception, though. This will depend on how often you will get `false`, how many constants you have, and how long the stack trace is (e.g. how deep this is called).

If you need this often (for the same enum), it might be better to create once a HashSet or a HashMap mapping the names to the enum values.

Comment: @jjn: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29 Or, better, just run and experience yourself.

Comment: @Balus, ah, thanks.  I didn't realize it was a generic method.

Comment: [It takes the actual enum type as the first parameter for this reason.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String)).

Comment: Huh, three answers before mine :-)

Comment: I'm having difficulty getting this to compile - getting this error: 
    > expected public boolean enumTypeContains(Class<E extends Enum<E>> e, String s) {

Comment: The `E` has to be definied as method type parameter: `public <E extends Enum<E>> boolean enumTypeContains(Class<E> e, String s)`. I fixed the answer.

Comment: +1 for doing it in constant time and not linear (depending on the implementation of `valueOf()`)

Comment: @BugsPray ... BalusC corrected the error faster than I could. Thanks for noting.

Comment: @BalusC: thanks for changing it to the right syntax. (I just wanted to edit it.)

Comment: Truly it works. The Question is now which of the proposed solutions works better ;)

Answer (score 3):

I found another variant which has neither to iterate all enum constants nor to throw an exception ... but it is implementation specific, i.e. uses undocumented methods. It works for Sun's JDK 1.6.0_20 (and was made by reading the source code from 1.6.0_13).

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> boolean enumTypeContains(Class<E> e, String s) {
    try {
        Method enumDir = Class.class.getDeclaredMethod("enumConstantDirectory");
        enumDir.setAccessible(true);
        Map<?,?> dir = (Map<?,?>)enumDir.invoke(e);
        return dir.containsKey(s);
    }
    catch(NoSuchMethodException ex) {
        throw new Error(ex);
    }
    catch(IllegalAccessException ex) {
        throw new Error(ex);
    }
    catch(InvocationTargetException ex) {
        throw new Error(ex.getCause());
    }
}
```

If we were in the `java.lang` package, this could simply look like this:

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> boolean enumTypeContains(Class<E> e, String s) {
    return e.enumConstantDirectory().containsKey(s);
}
```

This uses the method `Class.enumConstantDirectory()`, which (on first call) creates and (later only) returns a map with all the enum constants as values, their names as key. (Just such a map one could also create manually.)

This method is used internally by `Enum.valueOf(Class, String)`, and supposedly also by `EnumType.valueOf(String)` (depends on compiler).

On the first call of `enumConstantDirectory` or `getEnumConstants()`, a private helper method invokes `EnumType.values()` (which is implemented by the compiler). The result is then reused for following calls of these two methods.

Comment: The specification of needing to be in `java.lang` for `enumConstantDirectory()` solves a long-time issue of mine ☺